# Project won't launch on Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I've been trying to switch from the Google Eclipse Plugin to Cloud Tools for Eclipse, but I can't get a working launch configuration.

When I try to launch the project, the progress shows

> Preparing launch delegate...: Launching delegate...

until it is finally aborted with

> Server App Engine Standard at localhost (2) was unable to start within
>   240 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the
>   timeout in the server editor.

It's a maven project with Java on App Engine.

I have created a hello world maven project which launches fine.

When I examine the `org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpX` folder of the hello world project, I see various files and directories such as `index.jsp`, `META-INF` and `WEB-INF`, with `WEB-INF/lib` containing the maven dependency jars.

The same folder for my project contains only `WEB-INF/classes` which contains a wierd collection of files, including another `WEB-INF` with an empty `lib`

I'm running "Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 4.5 and later    1.2.0.201706082053" on Oxygen Release (4.7.0), although the issues has always existed since I first tried to migrate end of 2016

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Google Plugin Eclipse, but in my case I am not even able to sign in

Comment: @Alex Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Kumar yes, my Properties > Deployment Assembly was broken. I could correct it manually to start the dev server, but updating the maven project configuration would break it again. I then had to remove the m2e stuff from the pom.xml so the Deployment Assembly would not break anymore. Last time I checked, it worked

Answer (score -1):

tomcat unable to start within 240 seconds, go to server view Double click on your server, you can see Right corner of the server property Window max `Time out` option, change it to more the `240 second`. and also check your configuration.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not a Tomcat, the app engine dev environment uses a Jetty. Anyway, it shouldn't take that long; there is nothing happening in that time and it never took so long with the original eclipse plugin. Plus there is the issue with the completely weird webserver startup directory which doesn't contain .class files or jars. Anything specific I should check in the configuration?